# How can I properly write the following if statement with getLabel()

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the following error and would like to know how to rewrite this code properly.

> ReferenceError: Function function getLabel() {/* */} can not be used as the left-hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator. (line 61, file "DLContactsToSheet")

```
    var Phones = "";    
for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getPhones().length;g++)
{
  if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() = "MOBILE_PHONE") {
    Phones += "C: "
  } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() = "WORK_PHONE") {
    Phones += "W: "
  } else if (contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel() = "HOME_PHONE") {
    Phones += "H: "
  } else {
    Phones += "O: "
  }
  Phones += contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getPhoneNumber();
  Phones += "\n";
}
try{ContactArray.push(Phones);}
  catch(e){ContactArray.push("N/A")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the reference error is caused by an '=' rather than an '==' in your conditions.

Rewriting the conditions as `if (phone.getLabel() == 'MOBILE_PHONE') { /* ... */ }` etc should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hard code them, in order to fetch them.

### Code

```
function fieldType() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), phones = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var con = contacts[i], f = ContactsApp.Field;
    var c = con.getPhones(f.MOBILE_PHONE), w = con.getPhones(f.HOME_PHONE), h = con.getPhones(f.WORK_PHONE);
    phones = getNumber(phones, c, "C: ");
    phones = getNumber(phones, w, "W: ");
    phones = getNumber(phones, h, "H: ");
  }
}

function getNumber(phones, type, prefix) {
  var typeNumbers = [];
  var pNumber = type.length > 0 ? type.map( function (d) { return prefix + d.getPhoneNumber() + "\n"; }) : null; 
  if(pNumber) {
    typeNumbers.push(pNumber);
  }
  return phones.concat(typeNumbers);
}
```

### Note

See method description for more info: **[getPhoneNumber()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/phone-field#getPhoneNumber())**

Comment: Thanks Jacob! my code was just a section of a larger function which already had contacts and i defined. therefore i implemented your code accordingly. Now...it worked but it only grabbed one number for each contact. I believe i would need to replace the for() field to the length of contacts.getPhones() so it repeats for every phone number before moving to the next contact.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jacob, I'm still having a hard time implementing your method. (I am not a programmer which is probably why the answer is not obvious. The method below using == vs = seems to work. If it is not a stable/ efficient method than I would need further assistance to implement your method. I could post my whole script if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store the value for each iteration in a variable before any conditional statements. A case-switch statement is probably also better suited for this.

```
for ( var g=0;g<contacts[i].getPhones().length;g++)
{
  var phone_type = contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getLabel()
  switch(phone_type) {
     case "MOBILE_PHONE":
         Phones += "C: "
         break;
     case "WORK_PHONE":
         Phones += "W: "
         break;
     case "HOME_PHONE":
         Phones += "H: "
         break;
     default:
         Phones += "O: "
  } 
  Phones += contacts[i].getPhones()[g].getPhoneNumber();
  Phones += "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Korede, this method made all numbers start with O: